# yii get filetype and filesize of the file upload-

Tags: file, yii, types, upload, size

I need help to get file and type of the file which i upload.

My controller is next:

```
public function actionUpload()
    {
        $model=new Entryfile;
        $exstansion = Extansion::model()->findAll();
        $some = array();
        foreach ($exstansion as $key=>$value)
        $some[$value->idExt]=$value->ExtansionName;
        if(isset($_POST['Entryfile'])) {
             $model->attributes=$_POST['Entryfile'];
             //$model->uUserID = $_POST['User']['uUserID'];
             //Yii::import('ext.helpers.EDownloadHelper'); 
             //EDownloadHelper::download(Yii::getPathOfAlias('dms.upload').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'name');
             $model->eeFileName=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'eeFileName');
             if($model->save()) {
                 $model->eeFileName->saveAs('upload/'.$model->eeFileName->name);
                 $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->eeEntryFileID));
             }
        }
        $this->render('upload',array('model'=>$model, 'exstansion'=>$some));
    }
```

I need solution for file size and file type.
I want to save file and size in database table.
But I need step by step instruction, in code if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file size by `getSize()` method:

```
$size=$model->eeFileName->getSize();
```

and you can get file type by using `getType()`:

```
$type=$model->eeFileName->getType();
```

For more information check the `CUploadedFile` [Documents](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile).

Comment: Thank you I will try to use this advice to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

please read all the properties and methods in the given below documentation link[Click Me!!!](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile)

And your requirement is checking file size either use the public property `size` or public method `getSize()` but for file type don't use `getType()`.

Instead of `getType()` method you use `CFileHelpe::getMimeType()` [Click Me!!!](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileHelper#getMimeType-detail) because `getType()` won't check that on serverside.

Comment: Thank you for your asistance. i will send feedback if I resolve this.

Comment: sure any doubts please ask

Comment: CFileHelper::getMimeTypeByExtension() this is also one way which i find on this link: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/2613-cfilehelpergetmimetype-not-working/

Comment: good reply but `getMimeType()` last paramater by default `TRUE` so you just use this method Determines the MIME type of the specified file. This method will attempt the following approaches in order:

    finfo,
    mime_content_type,
    getMimeTypeByExtension, when $checkExtension is set true.

Answer (score 0):

1. For getting Extension

   ```
    $extension = $model->file->extension;
   ```
2. For getting Size

   ```
    $size = $model->file->size;
   ```